# Add custom fields on Yii profile fields

Tags: php, yii

I am using this modules- `yii-user.2mx.org` to create a user profiles, i added to `profile_field` and to `profile` tables, the field - "address", but i got this error in regiser page and edit profilr page.

```
Property "Profile.address " is not defined.
framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(143)

 {
134         if(isset($this->_attributes[$name]))
135             return $this->_attributes[$name];
136         elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->columns[$name]))
137             return null;
138         elseif(isset($this->_related[$name]))
139             return $this->_related[$name];
140         elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->relations[$name]))
141             return $this->getRelated($name);
142         else
143             return parent::__get($name);
144     }
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: post your Profile model code. does it have `public $address` declared somewhere in the class?

Comment: if i add "public $address" in model, the field show on edit profile page but cant save any data, the problem is that, this models i have the option to add user fields by user managment but uts still not working

Comment: ok i manage to find the problem, i just clear the cache and for some reason now its perfect, thanx